# inherited function odoo python

Tags: python, odoo

i  want to inherit function in module 'hr_holidays' that calculate remaining leaves the function is :

### hr_holiday.py:

```
def _get_remaining_days(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context=None):
    cr.execute("""SELECT
            sum(h.number_of_days) as days,
            h.employee_id
        from
            hr_holidays h
            join hr_holidays_status s on (s.id=h.holiday_status_id)
        where
            h.state='validate' and
            s.limit=False and
            h.employee_id in %s
        group by h.employee_id""", (tuple(ids),))
    res = cr.dictfetchall()
    remaining = {}
    for r in res:
        remaining[r['employee_id']] = r['days']
    for employee_id in ids:
        if not remaining.get(employee_id):
            remaining[employee_id] = 0.0
    return remaining
```

i had create my own module that inherited to `hr_holidays` and try this code to inherit but it isnt work

---

myclass.py

```
class HrHolidays(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'hr.holidays'

    interim = fields.Many2one(
        'hr.employee',
        string="Interim")
    partner_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string="Customer")
    remaining_leaves = fields.Char(string='Leaves remaining')


    def _get_remaining_days(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context=None):
        res = super(hr_holidays,self)._get_remaining_days(cr, uid, ids, name, args, context)
        return res
```

---

please help me

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call super with `HrHolidays` and pass just name and args to `_get_remaining_days` method and override `remaining_leaves` field:

**Python**

```
class HrHolidays(models.Model):
_inherit = 'hr.employee'

@api.model
def _get_remaining_days(self):
    res = super(HrHolidays, self)._get_remaining_days(name='', args={})
    for record in self:
        if record.id in res:
            record.remaining_leaves = res.get(record.id)

    return res

remaining_leaves = fields.Float(compute='_get_remaining_days',
                    string='Remaining Legal Leaves')
```

Comment: hi, i have try your code but i get this error : TypeError: _get_remaining_days() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the right Class in super():

```py
res = super(HrHolidays, self)._get_remaining_days(
    cr, uid, ids, name, args, context)
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all , 
but i got problem in the field ,i want to award my function to my field i have done that but isn't work :

```
    remaining_leaves = fields.Function(_get_remaining_days,string='Leaves')
```

i got this error
[image]

Comment: you're mixing old api and new api calls...use this `remaining_leaves = fields.Integer(compute='_get_remaining_days', string='Leaves')`

Comment: and you should have added this to your question instead of posting this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

i think that  function work but i couldnt show it by fields.function

```
   remaining_leaves = fields.Function(_get_remaining_days,string='Leaves')
```