# How to overwrite a v7 onchange method using new API?

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

I am trying to add some functionality to an existing onchange method. This one is declared in v7, and I want to use v8. The method is `onchange_product_id` of the model `stock.move`.

So I have declared my v8 onchange method (with the same name of the v7 method I want to overwrite). I also re-declared the affected field, `product_id`, because if not, my onchange method is not called (in the redefinition I have only set the comodel name, because it is expected to get the rest of the attributes from the original declaration).

This is my code:

```
product_id = fields.Many2one(
    comodel_name='product.product',
)

@api.v8
@api.onchange('product_id')
def onchange_product_id(self):
    _logger.info('*' * 80)
    self.ensure_one()
    result = super(StockMove, self).onchange_product_id(
        self.product_id, self.location_id, self.location_dest_id,
        self.picking_id.partner_id)
    return result
```

Now, the problem: I do not even see the log message, because I get this error:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

If I modify the decorator @api.v8 and I write @api.v7 instead, I get the error asking for more arguments in the definition of the onchange method.

I also tried to replace the `product_id` field in the XML view, to avoid calling the onchange method with several parameters, but the result was the same:

```
<field name="product_id" position="replace">
    <field name="product_id"/>
</field>
```

The old XML call of the method is this one:

```
<field name="product_id" on_change="onchange_product_id(product_id,location_id,location_dest_id, parent.partner_id)"/>
```

Can anyone help me, please? I found several questions related to this one in SO but no response helped me for this case.

*Note: I do not want to avoid `Super` and translate all the code of the old onchange method to the new API. It must be a better way to manage this. Isn't it?*

Comment: @czoeliner is right...but this is almost a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366140/inherited-function-odoo-python/39368724#39368724

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate or almost, because the focus here is on the onchange mechanism in utilisation of the new api AND old api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```py
@api.multi
def onchange_product_id(
        self, product_id, location_id, location_dest_id, partner_id):
    self.ensure_one()
    result = super(StockMove, self).onchange_product_id(
        product_id, location_id, location_dest_id, partner_id)

    # your result manipulation here

    return result
```

The decorator `multi` will encapsulate the parameters `cr`, `uid`, `ids` and `context` so you will need all other parameters. Maybe you will need some default values on the last parameters, but i don't know the original method, so i can't tell.

Comment: Thank you @CZoellner. With that code there are no errors, but I cannot have the advantages of v8 `@api.onchange` decorator inside the method. And due to that, at the end of the method I will have to update `value` dictionary in `result` variable to apply my changes (instead of doing `self.my_field = 'my_value'`).

Comment: Yep that's correct. But old onchange methods unfortunately aren't that compatible with the new api.

Comment: What a disaster then :( thank you very much for your help.